# Uploaded to AppStore with warnings - what is the impact?

Tags: icons, app-store, warnings, appstore-approval

I recently uploaded an app to the App Store, and it's now in the "Waiting for Review" Stage. I received the following warnings, however, and am wondering what the impact of them will be. Basically, should I cancel the upload, fix the warnings and re-submit, or just wait till the next release?

```
    Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0. 

    Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0.

    Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0. 

    Potential Loss of Keychain Access - The previous version of software has an application-identifier value of ['myname'] and the new version of software being submitted has an application-identifier of ['myname']. This will result in a loss of keychain access. For more information, please consult https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html 

    Missing 64-bit support - Beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need to follow the same requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.
```

Comment: Did they eventually approve it? I'm gonna have the same issue (lack of 64-bit support) but I need to push that last update in order to migrate users to a different app (which has 64-bit support). Do you think I have any chance to get it approved?

Comment: Sorry, no chance. The deadline was June 1.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do:

Leave the current version in review, if they accept it then that's great, if not that's ok too. Meanwhile, fix the issues they pointed out. You can either use that new code as new version or, if they rejected, use it as your initial version.

I do think they'll let you pass with the issues because they are just *recommendations* as it says in the warnings.

**EDIT**

I did not see the bottom warning, if you submitted before Feb 1st then you're fine but if not, they'll definitely reject. Make sure to fix the 64bit support.

Comment: It's an update to an existing app, so the warning doesn't apply (the date for those is June 1. Thanks.

Comment: Oh ok, sounded like it's the first upload of the app. Sorry then.